# What is the most efficient way of downloading SQL / file structure data to iPad app

Tags: php

Currently i have:

A server that has mySQL installed and accessed by PHP scripts.
All data is in SQL database including photos.

What i want to do is move the photos out the database and into their own file structure (that bit i can do) what i don't know is how to get all the string data out the database and photos into one return message, potentially I'm talking a fe hundred rows of data.

Currently i perform sql query and have to do the following

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $encodepic = base64_encode($row['IMAGE']);
        $posts[] = array($row['ID'],$row['COL1'], $row['COL2'], $row['COL3'], $row['COL4'], $encodepic, $row['COL5'], $row['COL6'], $row['COL7']);
    }
    echo json_encode($posts);
```

If i change the $row['IMAGE'] for the file (obviously read it first, won't that make system really slow?

Is there a better way full stop of doing what I'm trying to do

Also for code tidiness i want to send the dictionary down so other end (unless this makes system inefficient)

Thanks

Comment: get everything except image this way. Instead image send URL (or something) where you can find specific image and make another request (do it asynchronously for better user experience - especially if you are talking about hundreds of images)

Comment: so for example if i had 5 rows of data, id send one message requesting this, the reply would be json,   would i then have to send 5 requests for the five different photos or is it possible to send several photos in one message?

Comment: its better to do 5 parallel requests.